# sqlite3 C API containing two databases, creating tables in one effecting the results produced by other

Tags: c, database, sqlite

I am trying to use two databases for my project. One is already created called as the EPG database containing many tables and entries. The other one is my own database called as the REC database.When I open my own database I want to create the a table present in it. So there are three functions namely:

```
   re_rec_db_init();
   create_table();
   re_epg_db_init();
```

The code for the re_db_db_init() is like this:

```
   void re_epg_db_init(void)
{
    int status = sqlite3_initialize();

    s_dbepg_path=re_dbepg_get_path(); //get the path of the database

    //openrecDB

 status=sqlite3_open_v2(s_dbepg_path,&s_re_dbepg,SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY,NULL);
    //check status
      if(status!=SQLITE_OK){
   printf("\n\nerror occured in opening epg database \n");
    exit(0);
                 }

 status=sqlite3_extended_result_codes(s_re_dbepg,1);
  printf("\n\nstatus for opening the epg db is = %d \n",status);

   }
```

Only difference in re_rec_init would be a different path,handle name and mode (SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE)

Next, the create_table() fn will help me create a different table in the rec database. Its looks something like this:

```
void  create_table(void)
 {
    int status;
    char *sql_new;
    char *zErr;
    sql_new="create table if not exists test(Eventid VARCHAR(128) primary key,Title VARCHAR(128))";
    status=sqlite3_exec(s_re_dbrec,sql_new,NULL,NULL,&zErr);
    if(status==SQLITE_OK || status==SQLITE_DONE)
    {
    printf("\n\n table ready!! \n");
    }
    else
    {
    printf("\n\n table status: %d",status);
    }

  }
```

I want the program to query the epg database for a given title and return the Eventid. But the problem arises due to this create_tables method. when I let it execute the Eventid returned is null. Whereas when I comment it out, the Eventid is returned out perfectly.The outputs for the two cases are

case1: when table is created

```
    status for opening the rec db is = 0 

    table ready!!

    enter the title to be queried:Looney Tunes

    the entered title is:Looney Tunes

    status for opening the epg db is = 0 

    success in reading the query!

    Event id of the title is:(null) //wrong!
```

case2: when create_table is commented out

```
  status for opening the rec db is = 0 

  enter the title to be queried:Looney Tunes

  the entered title is:Looney Tunes

  status for opening the epg db is = 0 

  success in reading the query!

  Event id of the title is:00010006014124ed //correct result!
```

I really don't know how this is happening.While reading the query I am using a standard sqlite3_prepare_v2,sqlite3_step commands to get the event id. Please help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its seems your sqlite db pointer is referencing your new created db and not updated by next initialize. also your code is not reflecting what are your doing exactly. give some precise code simple.

```
sqlite3 *dbfile, *dbfile2;
```

you can try insert/update/delete/create inside a open connection. must change the connection pointer into currently using db.

```
bool ConnectDB (sqlite3 dbfile)
{
    if ( sqlite3_open(DB, &dbfile) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        isOpenDB = true;
        return true;
    }        

    return false;
}

void DisonnectDB ()
{
        if ( isOpenDB == true ) 
    {
    sqlite3_close(dbfile)
    }
}
```

Comment: s_re_dbepg and s_re_dbrec(not mentioned here) are the pointers (handles) to the two databases.. Therefore in order to do any manipulation to the databases i use their respective handles..   definations of them are "sqlite3 *s_re_dbepg" and "sqlite3 *s_re_dbrec" respectively.

Comment: both the connections are open and have different pointers.. my code is still stuck in that problem.